# How to create a generator of lines from multiple files in Python

Tags: python, generator

What is wrong with the following generator?

```
for file in file_list:
    fh = open(file, 'r')
    while True :
        yield fh.readline()
    fh.close()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you never break out of your infinite loop, because it yields lines from only a single file forever.

Check out [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) for this kind of problem. It should suffice to do it like this:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(your_list_of_filenames):
    process(line)
```

You have to define the `process` function according to your ends, of course.

Comment: That old doc page made me shiver. Here’s a [current one](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html).

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_all_lines(file_list):
    for f in file_list:
        with open(f) as fd:
            for line in fd:
                yield line.strip()

for line in get_all_lines(["a", "b"]):
    print line
```

where

```
$ cat a
a1
a2

$ cat b
b1
b2
```

output:

```
$ ./g.py 
a1
a2
b1
b2
```